# PIC 16F18 - Excessive program memory usage when multiplying by a floating point number

Tags: c, math, floating-point, pic

I have what appears to me a strange problem. It is better illustrated in the attached picture.
I am using a PIC 16F18323 with MPLAB and XC8 writing in C.
The program memory of the PIC is only 2KB so I need to keep it down as low as possible.
The problem is when I try and do a calculation the program memory usage jumps up by 40-50%.
The calculation I am doing is simple:

```
int blue;
int red;
blue = 4 * 1.5;
```

This is fine and takes up next to zero memory as one would expect.
However if I do another, similar calculation, like this:

```
int blue = 4;
int red;
red = blue * 1.5;
```

The program memory usage jumps to 40-50% as shown in the picture.

Thanks in advance.

[Picture ------ Upper image: low mem. Lower image: high mem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxliZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16F18323 does not have a floating-point unit, meaning that it cannot natively perform a floating-point operations. As a result, the compiler must emulate floating-point operations in software, and subsequently must emit a lot of code for even a single floating-point operation.

The first operation involves a constant expression and hence does not involve floating-point operations on the chip.

For your specific example, you may consider an integer-based approach instead:

```
red = blue + (blue / 2);
```

or alternatively (if your compiler does not generate efficient code for division by powers of two):

```
red = blue + (blue >> 1);
```

Note that the result may differ slightly due to rounding. Additionally, note that shifting signed types (such as your `int`) is *implementation-defined*; the XC8 compiler [defines](https://microchipdeveloper.com/tls2101:shift-operators) a shift on a signed value as a sign-extending arithmetic shift, which is what we want.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much for a concise and helpful answer.

Comment: @AlphaModular No problem. Your question was well-worded and had sufficient detail which helped make it easily answerable. If this completely solved the original issue you were having, you can mark the question as answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer. In general, I encourage doing so for all of the questions you ask, once you have answers you're happy with.